# Why is my first drop down getting refreshed in a cascaded setup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to setup a cascaded drop down box where the first one will result in the second one's value being changes and so on. I have some markup like this:

```
<form id="ddlSelections" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDL1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDL2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnDDL1Change" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnDDL2Change" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL3" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

And my code-behind is something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateDDL1();
}

private void populateDDL1()
{
    DDL1.Items.Clear();
    // -- populate from SQL
}

protected void OnDDL1Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DDL2.Items.Clear();
    // -- populate from SQL
}
```

This is working except that everytime I click on the first drop down box, the values in the second drop down box get populated but the values in the first drop down box are being re-populated i.e. it looks like `populateDDL1()` is being called which of course will not be called unless `Page_Load` is called! I am failing to understand why this is the case. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are populating the first dropdownlist on every page load.
You need to do that only on the first load.
Wrap your `populateDDL1` call in `if (!IsPostBack)`, which is a backward way of saying to only populate it the first time the page loads.

To test this, put a breakpoint on that line in `Page_Load`.

Just because it's an ajax-y `UpdatePanel` doesn't mean that the server-side methods don't run.

Comment: Oh boy! That solves it. Thank you so much. Will accept this in 7 more minutes :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I stubbed my foot, er, claw, on this one myself.

Comment: Ahaa... :) Also, thanks for the additional tip. I went and read an overview of the `UpdatePanel` and now everything is (hopefully) clear!